# MST trees checker (kruskal)

Tags: algorithm, tree, leda

I have implemented the kruskal's algorithm in c++ in LEDA library. 
So, i stored in a linked list the edges that belong to a MST, and those that are not .
So, i wanna make a checker program that checks if the edges are rigth, by checking if the MST cycle property is applied in my tree.
I have to make this program with LEDA's dynamic trees. 
But my overall question is :
If i have these edges:

```
`u1-u2 
 u3-u5 
 u2-u3
  ...`
```

How can I order them so that they are continues , like:

```
u1-u2
u2-u3
u3-u5
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need that. Call link on all of the tree edges (each edge has weight times -1 to change min to max), then for each non-tree edge uv, evert u and get the max (i.e., min times -1) cost from v to the root.

Comment: Hm.. im a bit confused :P can you explain me with an example pls ?

Comment: It'd be easier to have this conversation in the presence of some code.

Comment: My code is based on leda library . And its a bit hard to install it . I can give you some results of my code tho. Do you want ?

Comment: @user7337722 So you mean that a single element of the linked list contains both vertices like u1,u2?